# AWS cloud form task definition conditional command

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cloudformation

Let say I have an app that has the ability to run in a dry run mode, set by a flag on the command line; `myapp --dryrun`, and the CloudForm for its task definition is:

```
MyTaskDefinition
  Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
  Properties:
    ContainerDefinitions:
    - Name: myApp
      Image: user/myapp:latest
      Command:
      - ./myapp
      - --dryrun
      Environment:
      - Name: SOME_ENV_VAR
        Value: !Ref SomeEnvVar
```

I am trying to create a single CloudForm template for a Task Definition that can be used in a development and production environment, where the dry run flag is set only for the development environment.

Is there some way to set conditional command, or am I going to resort to a hacky string that I pass in like:

```
      Command:
      - ./myapp
      - !Ref DryRun
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The neatest solution was to use an `If` function, which sets the flag when true, and uses [`AWS::NoValue`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html#cfn-pseudo-param-novalue) if false.

`AWS::NoValue` will remove the property completely, meaning the command for true is `["./myapp", "--dryrun"]` and the command when false is `["./myapp"]`.

Unfortunately, there is no `Bool` type for CloudForm parameters, and so you have to pass this in as a `String`, and then use a `Condition` to convert from the `String` to a `Bool`.

```
MyTaskDefinition
  Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
  Properties:
    ContainerDefinitions:
    - Name: myApp
      Image: user/myapp:latest
      Command:
      - ./myapp
      - Fn::If:
        - UseDryRun
        - --dryrun
        - Ref: AWS::NoValue

Parameters:
  DryRun:
    Type: String
    AllowedValues: # No bool parameter in CFN
    - true
    - false

Conditions:
  UseDryRun: !Equals [ !Ref DryRun, true ]
```